# Compilation finished with exit code 2

Tags: go, kubectl

I'm trying to run the example here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration

I have set my GOROOT and GOPATH but still having problems. When I run the build I see the following error.

```
GOROOT=/usr/lib/golang #gosetup
GOPATH=/home/sbadakhc/go #gosetup
/usr/lib/golang/bin/go build -o /tmp/___go_build_main_go /home/sbadakhc/go/src/github.com/sbadakhc/gopro/main.go #gosetup
# k8s.io/client-go/transport
../../../k8s.io/client-go/transport/round_trippers.go:70:11: cannot convert klog.V(9) (type klog.Verbose) to type bool
../../../k8s.io/client-go/transport/round_trippers.go:72:11: cannot convert klog.V(8) (type klog.Verbose) to type bool
../../../k8s.io/client-go/transport/round_trippers.go:74:11: cannot convert klog.V(7) (type klog.Verbose) to type bool
../../../k8s.io/client-go/transport/round_trippers.go:76:11: cannot convert klog.V(6) (type klog.Verbose) to type bool

Compilation finished with exit code 2
```

The code.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/errors"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    //
    // Uncomment to load all auth plugins
    _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth"
    //
    // Or uncomment to load specific auth plugins
    // _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth/azure"
    // _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth/gcp"
    // _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth/oidc"
    // _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth/openstack"
)

func main() {
    // creates the in-cluster config
    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // creates the clientset
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    for {
        pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(metav1.ListOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf("There are %d pods in the cluster\n", len(pods.Items))

        // Examples for error handling:
        // - Use helper functions like e.g. errors.IsNotFound()
        // - And/or cast to StatusError and use its properties like e.g. ErrStatus.Message
        _, err = clientset.CoreV1().Pods("default").Get("example-xxxxx", metav1.GetOptions{})
        if errors.IsNotFound(err) {
            fmt.Printf("Pod not found\n")
        } else if statusError, isStatus := err.(*errors.StatusError); isStatus {
            fmt.Printf("Error getting pod %v\n", statusError.ErrStatus.Message)
        } else if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Found pod\n")
        }

        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

This code should build correctly.

Comment: What exactly is unclear in the error message?

Comment: The last [commit](https://github.com/kubernetes/klog/commit/cd60aa438f9c750641d5feacd2999e58df8af28f#diff-fb778b051a785bbb2eea40d6a00a3a21L1111-R1160) to `klog` made a braking change. Any code depending on the klog package's `Verbose` type to have the underlying type `bool`, which is the case with `kubernetes/client-go`, will break. If you can, get an older version of klog on your system.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for bringing that to my attention. I will see if I can find an older version to test with.

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/klog/releases/tag/v0.4.0 should work

Answer (score 0):

I got the build to finally execute but it seems there are a number of factors.

1. Removed the ../../../k8s.io from my src dir.
2. Avoid using the latest master branch of the client-go by explicitly declaring a version in the go.mod file.

Re-running the build fetched the new sources and the stable version of the client. The build executed without errors.

Comment: FYI, if you're using Go modules you wouldn't need to change anything under $GOPATH (e.g. your `../../../k8s.io` directory wouldn't be used) and a `go get github.com/kubernetes/klog@v0.4.0` run within your module would update your `go.mod` file to use the version mentioned by mkopriva.

Comment: Thanks @DaveC. I thought I was probably missing a trick there!